# Adapter in a ListView in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, listadapter

I'm trying to complement a code that controls a custom ListView through three classes: `AdapterListView`,`ItemListView` and `MainActivity`.

So far, the code only manages to enter data and images (inserted by code) through `AdapterListView`. Within that class, want to know how use other features such as add or remove items by the application.

**Below the three project classes:**

**AdapterListView**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by LuizHMU on 2/7/15.
*/
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListView> itens) {
    //Itens que preencheram o listview
    this.itens = itens;
    //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

/**
 * Retorna a quantidade de itens
 *
 * @return
 */
public int getCount() {
    return itens.size();
}

/**
 * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public ItemListView getItem(int position) {
    return itens.get(position);
}

/**
 * Sem implementação
 *
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Pega o item de acordo com a posção.
    ItemListView item = itens.get(position);
    //infla o layout para podermos preencher os dados
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);

    //atravez do layout pego pelo LayoutInflater, pegamos cada id relacionado
    //ao item e definimos as informações.
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(item.getTexto());
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview)).setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());

    return view;
}
}
```

**ItemListView**

```
/**
* Created by LuizHMU on 2/7/15.
*/
public class ItemListView {

private String texto;
private int iconeRid;

public ItemListView() {
}

public ItemListView(String texto, int iconeRid) {
    this.texto = texto;
    this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
}

public int getIconeRid() {
    return iconeRid;
}

public void setIconeRid(int iconeRid) {
    this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
}

public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
}
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

private ListView listView;
private AdapterListView adapterListView;
private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Pega a referencia do ListView
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    //Define o Listener quando alguem clicar no item.
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    createListView();
}

private void createListView() {
    //Criamos nossa lista que preenchera o ListView
    itens = new ArrayList<ItemListView>();
    ItemListView item1 = new ItemListView("Felpudo", R.drawable.felpudo);
    ItemListView item2 = new ItemListView("Felpudão", R.drawable.felpudo1);
    ItemListView item3 = new ItemListView("Felpudinho", R.drawable.felpudo2);

    itens.add(item1);
    itens.add(item2);
    itens.add(item3);

    //Cria o adapter
    adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, itens);

    //Define o Adapter
    listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
    //Cor quando a lista é selecionada para ralagem.
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    //Pega o item que foi selecionado.
    ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(arg2);
    //Demostração
    Toast.makeText(this, "Você Clicou em: " + item.getTexto(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How do I add or remove data in the list by the application using the class AdapterListView. @Willis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Adapter:

```
public void addItem(ItemListView item){
 items.add(item);
 notifyDatasetChanged();
}

public void removeItem(int positionToRemove){
 items.remove(positionToRemove);
 notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```

To further explain whats happening, the adapter is the controller, the middle step between the information and the way of displaying it in the view (ListView). The information in this case is given to the adapter through the items list, so basically manipulating the list and calling notifyDataSetChanged() will change the views displayed to the user.

Hope i was of help.

Comment: how do I call these methods in my MainActivity? @jvrodrigues

Comment: Well, easy enough, adapterListView.addItem(yourItem); and adapterListView.removeItem(position);

Comment: Thanks for your help. As it will be when I run my application? I'll be able to add or remove items from the list for him? For your explanation, I'm adding and removing items only by code. @jvrodrigues

Comment: Well you could add or remove items in a button or after some input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple methods like this in your activity :

```
private void addItemToList(ItemListView item){
    if(item != null){
       itens.add(item) 
    }
}
```

(to remove cells use list.remove())

Add this in your adapter :

```
public void loadNewList(List<ItemListView> list){
    if(itens != null){
        itens.clear;
    }
    itens = list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

nb : you should use the holder pattern for the list cells :)

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you have `listView` attribut. In `onCreate()` method you can do this:

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                final ItemListView item = (ItemListView) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                // Do whatever you want here !!
                adapterListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
```